# CompareTo behaviour for double.NaN and double.NegativeInfinity

Tags: c#, double, nan, infinity, icomparable

I was doing some statistical operations in C# (.Net 4) with `double[]` then i found some strange behavior with `CompareTo` method and `double.NaN`. when I try this code:

```
double.NaN.CompareTo(double.NegativeInfinity) //returns -1
```

It means `double.NaN` is even smaller than `double.NegativeInfinity`! can anyone explain why it is like this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: No, it means that for the case of sorting, NaN is considered less than negative infinity. I would venture a guess that the same rule is followed when comparing NegativeInfinity with null.

Comment: You're not likely to get any answer other than "that's what the specs say to do" or possibly some wild speculation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CompareTo does not tell you that one thing is smaller than another. It tells you one instance precedes (-), follows (+) or is interchangeable with (0) another instance when ordering instances.

The *why* here is really up to those designing behavior for primitives in the CLR.

[IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)'s purpose is for ordering instances of a type. So for NaN, a valid double value, the decision was made to order it *before* any other instance of the type.

Note that CompareTo is not necessarily the same, in meaning, or in intended use, as numeric greater than/less than operations. CompareTo is meant to provide an ordering over the set of values that double can take on. For example,

```
double.NaN.CompareTo(double.NaN)
```

will return 0. But

```
double.NaN == double.NaN
```

is false. Likewise,

```
double.NaN.CompareTo(double.NegativeInfinity)
```

returns -1, but

```
double.NaN < double.NegativeInfinity
```

returns false. So, the CompareTo method is not saying that mathematically double.NaN is smaller than double.NegativeInfinity. The less than operator in fact says that's not true. But it is saying that, when ordering values, double.NaN comes first.

Here is a link to the Double type's [LessThan Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.op_lessthan.aspx) documentation as well. Reading that as well as the meaning of [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) side by side should help clarify the difference in what the two methods are trying to express.

Answer (score 8):

[`double.NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) is less than negative infinity.

From metadata information they explained like;

```
public const double NegativeInfinity = -1.0 / 0.0

public const double NaN = 0.0 / 0.0;
```

From [`Double.CompareTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyxd1d26.aspx) method;

> Compares this instance to a specified double-precision floating-point
>   number and returns an integer that indicates whether the value of this
>   instance is less than, equal to, or greater than the value of the
>   specified double-precision floating-point number.

If *This instance is not a number (NaN) and value is a number*

[`Double.CompareTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyxd1d26.aspx) method returns *A negative integer*

Let's look at this sample (here is a *[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/YuwYbQ)*);

```
void Main()
{
    double a = double.NaN;
    double b = double.NegativeInfinity;
    Console.WriteLine(a.CompareTo(b));
}
```

Even when we look at IL code, `double.NaN` represents with `00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 FF` and `double.NegativeInfinity` represents with `00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 FF` ;

```
IL_0000:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 FF 
IL_0009:  stloc.0     
IL_000A:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 FF 
IL_0013:  stloc.1     
IL_0014:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0016:  ldloc.1     
IL_0017:  call        System.Double.CompareTo
IL_001C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

Comment: Hehe MSDN is incorrect: Double.NaN.CompareTo(double.NaN) returns 0, not -1. **Fortunately.** :-) Okay, I admit, MSDN tells that it's 0 when they both are NaN.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn MSDN is right. It says **Both this instance and value are not a number (NaN), PositiveInfinity, or NegativeInfinity. It returns zero .** So MSDN is correct I think.

Comment: Yes, I first read your answer with the incomplete info, then saw it on MSDN. You just edited it a bit too fast for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, comparing double.nan numerically to anything is meaningless.  But if you have a list of double and want to do something with it, you'd want them all at the end of the list so that you can do all meaningful work first and so that you can stop when you see the first one.  It's like a list where some items are null, they get shoved to the end.

A few cases where double.nan occurs:

```
Dim d1 as double = 0/0
Dim d2 as double = Double.PositiveInfinity / Double.PositiveInfinity
Dim d3 as double = Double.PositiveInfinity / Double.NegativeInfinity
Dim d4 as double = Double.PositiveInfinity / Double.PositiveInfinity
Dim d5 as double = Double.PositiveInfinity / Double.NegativeInfinity
```